# Solving the integral $\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\tan^3(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration

I've come across this integral recently (on a Facebook group):
$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\tan^3(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$ and have little to no clue how to solve it. Wolfram Alpha gives a numerical answer of approximately 0.209, but could not evaluate it 'manually'. My gut feeling is that it will involve some sort of contour integral, but I cannot see what might work. If anyone has any insight, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What sort of answer are you looking for?  Do you have any reason to believe the value is not a transcendental number (i.e., requires numerical methods, similar to the one(s) used by W.Alpha to get "0.209", to evaluate)?

Comment: I'm not really expecting any answer in particular. This was posed as a particularly difficult and interesting problem though, so I'm relatively confident it has a transcendental answer, else I feel this problem wouldn't be posed as 'interesting'. I thought I'd post it here in case anyone had any insight into it, as I am also confident this problem is beyond my level of education, but I'm always keen to learn of methods I haven't come across before.

Comment: May be you could avoid tking problems from Facebook. What about McDonald as a source of inspiration ? (I am just kidding, be sure). Cheers :-)

Comment: If the upper limit was $1$, Chebyshev quadrature would have come in handy

Answer (score 0):

I am skeptical about a closed form for this definite integral. Its numerical value is
$$0.20852064462921058579012825612057983198834121981775$$ which has not been identified by any inverse symbolic calculator. The closest found is
$$\frac 1 {10}\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{6}\right) \Big(\log(2)\Big) ^{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}=0.20852064115$$

What I suppose is that this could be done by series expansion to high order
$$\frac{\tan ^3(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=x^3 \left( 1+\frac{3 x^2}{2}+\frac{193 x^4}{120}+\frac{22979 x^6}{15120}+\frac{275197
   x^8}{201600}+\frac{48228793 x^{10}}{39916800}+O\left(x^{12}\right)\right)$$ and integrated termwise. Let us try with expansions up to $O(x^{2n+3})$ for the integrand. This would lead for the definite integral to the following values
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n  & \text{result for series expansion}    \\
 10 & 0.20840782763821602389366491327101465 \\
 20 & 0.20852027116982251348225379128240811 \\
 30 & 0.20852064289873138870614412907285772 \\
 40 & 0.20852064461992536661178971837443094 \\
 50 & 0.20852064462915641583336414649616403 \\
 60 & 0.20852064462921025212195797014568471 \\
 70 & 0.20852064462921058365488869446074788 \\
 80 & 0.20852064462921058577607189472019213 \\
 90 & 0.20852064462921058579003367910543448 \\
 100   & 0.20852064462921058579012760861728633 \\
\cdots &\cdots \\
\infty & 0.208520644629210585790128256120579832
\end{array}
\right)$$